# What would happen if the error term isn't independent of X in OLS?

Tags: least-squares, assumptions

I was reading Introduction to Statistical Learning 2nd edition chapter 3.1.2 when I came across the following sentence:

> We typically assume that the error term is independent of X.

Which made me wonder why do we have to assume that.

**What would happen if the error were *dependent* on X?**

**Also, what would be a good example of an error depending on X?**

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/411275/ols-regression-with-endogenous-variables could be of interest

Comment: The question would become *how* does the error depend on $X.$  The errors of many kinds of measurements are proportional to the magnitude of the quantity being measured, for instance.

Comment: Try an econometrics textbook. In many of them, consequences of violations of OLS assumptions are discussed in detail.